# Android SearchView Hide Keyboard on Start up

Tags: android, search, android-softkeyboard, searchview

I'm having a minor issue I'm trying to solve.
When I open my application, the keyboard shows to enter a query for the search view. However I just want the keyboard to appear when I click on the search view. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me.

/* Code used to hide focus */

```
searchView =(SearchView)view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
searchView.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: This will also prevent the view from gaining focus when it is desired.

Answer (score 7):

Use this attributes in your layout tag in XML file:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

or in manifest xml for your Activity add the property:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay! However, none of it works unfortunately. The keyboard is still showing on start up.

Comment: Sorry, I detected the error myself. I had placed: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" under application instead of Activity. Now it works fine! However, it still annoys me that the searchBar blinks (like if you are typing text into it) while the keyboard is hidden. Is it possible to solve this issue too?

Comment: Accept this answer an start another one.

Comment: Love it.  None of the solutions I've found for this problem worked for me.  The manifest change did it.

Comment: @Stanojkovic It probably wasn't accepted because it was an incomplete  answer. This is a very "hacky" way to solve the problem that relies on conflicting parameters overriding each other.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
searchView =(SearchView)view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
searchView.clearFocus();
```

Comment: This answer isn't exploiting bugs in the API. Thanks for adding it.

Answer (score 5):

This is work for me: clear focus in onResume() of  activity or fragment

```
objSearchView=(SearchView)view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);

 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        objSearchView.clearFocus();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for me I have to call both setFocusable(false) and clearFocus()

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        . . .
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        searchView.setFocusable(false);
        . . .
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        . . .
        searchView.clearFocus();
        . . .
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not use this:

```
searchInput = (SearchView) layout.findViewById(R.id.search);
searchInput.onActionViewExpanded();//<<<<------------------ don't use it.
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me
I used to this code Hide Keyboard and show a hint

```
 searchView =(SearchView)view.findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    
    searchView .setIconified(false);
    searchView .clearFocus();
```