# Not able to hide keyboard while using Search Widget

Tags: android

I am using Search Widget to implement search interface in my app in action bar. As soon as the activity starts the keyboard pops up even if I have not interacted with the search widget. So for that I added the attribute in the activity tag in manifest file **windowSoftInputMode** giving value either **stateHidden** or **stateAlwaysHidden** but this did not worked. So I tried to do it programmatically using the **hideSoftInputFromWindow** method but this also did not worked.

What does this causes to pop up the keyboard even after the attributes are set not to show and how to solve this issue? Please help!

Comment: You can use the following to hide the keyborad `YOUR_SERACHVIEW.setFocusable(false);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SearchView Hide Keyboard on Start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301094/android-searchview-hide-keyboard-on-start-up)

Comment: Ravindra Kushwaha - The answer in the link which you are saying that is possibly duplicate does not solves my issue.

Comment: **I have not down-voted your question** ..I have just provided the link u which is helpful for u.. @VaibhavDhude ...here are all we for the help...Have You tried the other solution to..I have just given the possible duplication mark..Do take it in other way..Here in **SO** votes comes on the basis of the quality of the question.You can edit your question and add what have u tried from the above link..And still it is not workable for u

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use this functions to show OR hide the keyboard:

```
/**
 * Hides the soft keyboard
 */
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 
0);
}
}

/**
 * Shows the soft keyboard
 */
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) 
    getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    view.requestFocus();
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set focus as false at first time when that screen loaded. By default when screen loaded, the focus goes to first edittext and Keyboard appears.set like this

```
view.setFocusable(false);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

and on clickListener of that view make that view as focused. by using 
view.requestFocus();

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the focus on any other view of the activity like this:

```
view.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I spotted the problem and solved the issue. I was using `android.widget.SearchView` and changed it to **`android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`**, after which I didn't even need to use `windowSoftInputMode` in the manifest or the `hideSoftInputFromWindow()` method. ***Please note!***